# Equation solving involving logarithm

Tags: logarithms

I need help solving this equation to find the variable $RC$:

$$V_c=V_{in}\left(1-\frac{e^{-t}}{RC}\right).$$

I already know $V_c$, $V_{in}$ and $t$. I always get it wrong so the $RC$ is negative. It represents time and so it shouldn't be.

Comment: Use $\LaTeX$. And what are Vin, Vc, RC?

Comment: Do you mean $y=a\ln(\frac{1-e^{-t}}{x})$?

Answer (score 1):

So,
$$V_{c}=V_{in}\left(1-\exp\left({\frac{-t}{RC}}\right)\right)$$
Divide by $V_{in}$ and subtract
$$\exp\left({\frac{-t}{RC}}\right)=1-\frac{V_{c}}{V_{in}}$$
Take logs
$$\frac{-t}{RC}=\ln\left(1-\frac{V_{c}}{V_{in}}\right)$$
and re-arrange
$$\frac{-t}{\ln\left(1-\frac{V_{c}}{V_{in}}\right)}=RC$$

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is $$V_c = V_{in}\cdot\frac{1-e^{-t}}{RC},$$ then multiply the equation by $RC$ and divide it by $V_c$ to get

$$RC=V_{in}\cdot\frac{1-e^{-t}}{V_c}$$ which is negative if $e^{-t} > 1$, so when $t<0$.

Comment: That's a good shout, I thought it to be $\exp(-t/RC)$ due to the relation between time delay and capacitance. You may have a good point there though.